# Create new child field collection programmatically

Tags: 8, entities

I have 2 field collections (Parent and child)

- Parent Field collection: Test Student Info
  machine name: field_test_student_info
- Child Field collection: Marks
  machine name: field_marks

In parent field collection have 1 field:

- Field1: Student Name
  machine name: field_student_name

In child field collection have 2 fields:

- Field1: English Marks
  machine name: field_eng_marks
- Field2: History Marks
  Machine name: field_history_marks

I have set field setting "unlimited" to child field collection (Marks). I just want to add new child field collection item programmatically.
I have tried below code but it's showing me error:

```
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface;
use Drupal\field_collection\Entity\FieldCollectionItem;

function CreateChildFC() {
  $node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load(770);
  $load = FieldCollectionItem::load(207); // Loading child FC from parent FC i.e Marks
  $field_collection_items = $load->field_marks;
  $field_collection_item = FieldCollectionItem::create(
   [
    'field_name' => 'field_marks', 
   ]
   );
  $field_collection_item->setHostEntity($node);
  $field_collection_item->set('field_eng_marks', '89');
  $field_collection_item->set('field_history_marks', '75');
  $load->field_marks[] = ['field_collection_item' =>   $field_collection_item];
  $node->save();
}
```

**Error**
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to _field_collection_field_item_list_full() must implement interface Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface, null given, called in /site/modules/contrib/field_collection/src/Entity/FieldCollectionItem.php on line 333 in _field_collection_field_item_list_full() (line 151 of modules/contrib/field_collection/field_collection.module).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try the code:

```
<?php 
use Drupal\field_collection\Entity\FieldCollectionItem;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

[.....]

  $node = Node::load(7);
  $field_collection_item = FieldCollectionItem::create(
    [
      'field_name' => 'field_test_student_info',
    ]
  );

  $field_collection_item->set('field_student_name', 'Student Name');

  $field_mark_collection = FieldCollectionItem::create(['field_name' => 'field_marks']);
  $field_mark_collection->set('field_english_marks', '1231');
  $field_mark_collection->set('field_history_marks', '123');
  $field_collection_item->field_marks[] = ['field_collection_item' => $field_mark_collection];
  $node->field_test_student_info = ['field_collection_item' => $field_collection_item];
  $field_collection_item->setHostEntity($node);
  $node->save();
```

You need create new collection field  `FieldCollectionItem::create(['field_name' => 'field_marks'])`

You can set value to the file child in field parent collection, it is same you when set value field collection in node, here you dont's need set `setHostEntity`, it will understand is the `field_collection_item`

As the code above I also checked it, and it worked.

You can refer to it [here](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2015-01-08/create-node-programatically-with#comment-10066624)

Goodluck