# Field collection item code not working

Tags: 8, hooks

Hi Every one I am trying to create new field collection item programmatically but code is not working. I want to create a number of field collection items but no Luck. My code is following.

```
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface;
use Drupal\field_collection\Entity\FieldCollectionItem;

function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) { 
if($form_id == 'my_form'){

for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {

$new_experience_item = FieldCollectionItem::create(['field_name' => 'field_collection_name']);

      }


    }

}
```

My first Question-> Can we run this code in the hook_form_alter?  If yes, Then why my code is not working perfectly?

Comment: Paragraphs is likely to replace field collection for Drupal 8 and adding default values to an entity form is easier to do in an entity hook, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/259275/create-any-number-of-paragraph-fields-in-a-multiple-value-field-on-node-create-f

Comment: Thanks for your response. But can You tell me is there is any problem in my code? Or Drupal 8 https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection/issues/2784931 apply this. My Drupal version is 8.7.0. My English is so week but hopefully you will understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

Paragraphs or Field Collection doesn't matter for your code. You need to add the newly created items to a field.

For example if the field collection field is in a node:

`$node->field_collection_name[] = $new_item;`

Not in a form alter hook, but in an entity create hook. See the [linked question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/259275/create-any-number-of-paragraph-fields-in-a-multiple-value-field-on-node-create-f).

Comment: Let me tell you my case. I have a field in profile named Experience and the field is field collection and unlimited.When the user apply to a job so I want to copy all the experience from the user profile. For this purpose I made a new field collection field and on the job page I load all the experience and want to create new field collection items to store that experience data.

Comment: for reference you can see this https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/268421/create-new-child-field-collection-programmatically

Comment: Then do this in a controller, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/236871/pre-fill-multiple-paragraphs-while-adding-node

Comment: I want this for field collection item ... Sorry I am very new to Drupal 8 module development

Comment: Use the code from your link and put it in a controller like in my link.